# Damaged external NTFS hard disk

Tags: windows, mount, ntfs, external-hdd

A few days ago, I used my external hard disk (a 2TB Seagate) in order to transfer some files on Windows Vista. During that, I noticed some malfunctions on my system (it was running too slow, Windows Explorer crashed).

When Explorer crashed, file transportation stopped. I was afraid, but I tried to access my files and it seemed to be working. I tried to open a movie (from the external disk) but it couldn't load. I thought of restarting, but this took sooo long... So I unplugged the hard disk and at that time it managed to shut down. I logged on to Windows Vista but the hard disk couldn't be mounted. I plugged it but nothing happened. I unplugged it and I heard this specific sound that notifies that something has been unplugged.

I thought of logging to Ubuntu 10.04 and see what I can do. I plugged the hard disk, but I couldn't see it. I opened GParted but I couldn't see it either. I tried with Disc Utility and there it was! I tried to `mount` it but a got an error message stating that an error occured with Windows, there is a file (0,0) that has problem or something like that. It suggested to log into Windows and run `chkdsk /f` and reboot twice.

The thing is that I am somehow afraid to do so because I don't really know the impact on that. Plus I don't trust doing even a check on Vista...

I finally risked it and I typed

```
chkdsk/f
```

on a `cmd`. I cannot, however, actually run it because I don't have admin privileges. So from search I found `chkdsk`, I right cliked and selected “run as administrator”. It run but I got a message like `NTFS file system`. It should check at the coming restart.

At that point I am mistaken. I thought that `f` meant `F` but this is not the case here...

Does anyone have any suggestions and advice?

---

I've tried with Partition Magic Bootable CD but I couldn't get my HDD mounted.

At first I thought of running a disk health. My device was named "Unknown" and I got the message
`/dev/sdb failed: No such device`

Then I tried with GParted but it couldn't find my HDD.

Finally I tried to mount it from a "mount utility" or sth like that but it couldn't be mounted.

The first time I tried I got an error

```
Run: Mount /dev/sdb 
Status: Finished with error(exit status 1)
udevil: error 64: unable to determine device fstype specify with -t
```

After that there was a list of all my drives. When I selected the external one I got the error message

```
Run: Mount /dev/sdb1
Status: Finished with error(exit status 18)
Failed to write lock '/dev/sdb1' : Resource temporalily unavailable
Error opening '/dev/sdb1':Resource temporalily unavailable
Failed to mount :Resource temporalily unavailable
```

The second time I tried to mount it I got a new error message

```
Run: Mount /dev/sdb
Status: Finished with error(exit status 1)
udevil: error 57: Cannot stat /dev/sdb: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: It looks like either the filesystem or the disk is damaged. Do run `chkdsk` as recommended (you can do it on another Windows computer). Be prepared to have to replace the disk and restore your files from a backup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Running `chkdsk` is working on `C`,right? I want to access `F`, so is it proper to do so? What option should I do? `f`, `r`, `i`? The fact is that I don't have another `windows` computer... What do you mean, "replace the disk"? Could it be broken? And how am I going to backup, if I don;t have access? Sorry if I ask too many questions, but I beleive you understand my anxiety!

Comment: I don't know how chkdsk works, I'm not a Windows expert. Try `chkdsk /?` (under Windows) to see a short description. It might be something like `chkdsk f:`.

Comment: I see...Can this be done in ubuntu?

Comment: I typed `chkdsk F: /i` for a quick check and I am waiting...It doesn't seem however to be doing something...

Comment: Having external drive plugged in causes serious problems on my system's speed. I unplugged it. As soon as I did it, the `chkdsk` has finished. The answer is that the file system isn;t `NTFS` but `RAW`. Is this bad?

Comment: @Thanos Yes, very bad. This means that the file system is heavily corrupted. I'd recommend taking the hard drive in to a professional *this*. *second*. Any further _touching_ this is just messing it up further. _NOTE: I normally don't advocate seeking professional help for something like this, but when the filesystem actually reads as `RAW` instead of `NTFS`, that's very, very serious._

Comment: The problem might be shown in Ubuntu but this is a Windows problems. So fix this with Windows. I consider this off topic.

Answer (score 0):

when you don't want to restore lost datas, and simply only want that
hard-disk works again ... you could (later) try this command for
to make hard-disk new like fresh from factory - best over night
(2 Tibi last a long time with dd like this) :

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/harddisk

harddisk stands for sda, sdb, or sdc whatever

When harddisk is external I would set it up on the side of it (upright).
Then let run the dd-command over night.

when dd-command like above is breaking off too early (before last cylinder),
then harddisk is broken and you could swap it (with warranty of manufactory for 2 years) against a new one at the manufactorer (not at trader).

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect it to a Windows PC, go to:

Here's How:

Click on the Start button and then choose Control Panel.

Click on the System and Security link.

Note: If you're viewing the Large icons or Small icons view of Control Panel, you won't see this link so just click on the Administrative Tools icon.

In the System and Security window, click on the Administrative Tools heading located near the bottom of the window.

In the Administrative Tools window, double-click on the Computer Management icon.

When Computer Management opens, click on Disk Management on the left side of the window, located under Storage.

After a brief loading period, Disk Management should now appear on the right side of the Computer Management window.

Note: If you don't see Disk Management listed, you may need to click on the |> icon to the left of the Storage icon.

You can now partition a hard drive, format a hard drive, change a drive's letter, or do whatever else you need to do in Windows 7/8/8.1 Disk Management tool.

You will then find your hard drive, format it.

I´m afraid that you may have ruined the hard drive if you were formatting it with Parted Magic and you stopped it.

Comment: Answer is purely Windows and, to me, makes this off topic.